# Get a List of Questions to Display on my External website

Tags: discussion, api

Similar to your flair that you can post an HTML snippet of and post on your blog site or elsewhere, is it possible to get, say, the most recent questions I asked or most recent questions by tag and display that on an external web site using an HTML snippet?

Or is there a REST API I can use to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, [there's an API](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/usage/). Here's a simple example that will display the title of the latest question you answered:

```js
<script>
var url = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/users/231716/answers?jsonp=?"
jQuery.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    alert("Brian's latest answer was to \"" + data.answers[0].title + "\".");
});
</script>
```